# How to warm-start pyomo with cplex?

Tags: cplex, pyomo

I am currently using cplex with pyomo from the command line using

`pyomo -solver=cplex model.py data.dat`

the results are saved in the file `results.json`.
How can I start cplex again using the previous results as a starting solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do more advanced things like loading a warmstart it is better to start using Pyomo by writing your own Python scripts. In your case, this might look like:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

# import the module that contains your model
import model

# load the data
instance = model.model.create_instance('data.dat')

# create a solver
cplex = SolverFactory("cplex")

# solve the first time (tee=True prints the cplex output)
status = cplex.solve(instance, tee=True)
assert str(status.solver.termination_condition) == 'optimal'

# solve the model a second time and create a warmstart file for cplex
status = cplex.solve(instance, warmstart=True, tee=True)
```

See the [scripting](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_scripts) section of the online Pyomo docs for more on this.